# Could interrupting a SQL query that was taking too long lead to a decrease in disk space?

Tags: windows, memory, sql, postgresql, virtual-memory

For a personal data analysis project, I was trying to find the most frequent 3 products that were being sold together by doing a self join (twice).

As the query was taking over 15 mins and the laptop fans seemed to be going into overdrive, I decided to stop it. This was all done through pgAdmin.

Upon checking immediately afterwards, I noticed that the size of my free space on the C drive decreased by 7GB (from the 15GB that it had been before).

Tried doing a `VACUUM` and a `VACCUM FULL` without any improvement.

Did some digging with WinDirStat and TreeSize and as far as I can tell, the file that changed during the time that the query was running was the `pagefile.sys` one.

Did the virtual memory somehow increase automatically? I am absolutely stumped by this. Thoughts?

One further thing I have tried was to clear the above mentioned `pagefile.sys` on computer shutdown but with no change in its size.

FWIW, this is the output for `VACUUM FULL VERBOSE ANALYZE`:

```
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_statistic"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_statistic": found 0 removable, 441 nonremovable row versions in 28 pages
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_type"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_type": found 2 removable, 635 nonremovable row versions in 15 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_type"
INFO:  "pg_type": scanned 15 of 15 pages, containing 633 live rows and 2 dead rows; 633 rows in sample, 633 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_foreign_table"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_foreign_table": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_foreign_table"
INFO:  "pg_foreign_table": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_authid"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_authid": found 0 removable, 15 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_authid"
INFO:  "pg_authid": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 15 live rows and 0 dead rows; 15 rows in sample, 15 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_statistic_ext_data"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_statistic_ext_data": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_statistic_ext_data"
INFO:  "pg_statistic_ext_data": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_opclass"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_opclass": found 0 removable, 177 nonremovable row versions in 3 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_opclass"
INFO:  "pg_opclass": scanned 3 of 3 pages, containing 177 live rows and 0 dead rows; 177 rows in sample, 177 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_am"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_am": found 0 removable, 7 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_am"
INFO:  "pg_am": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 7 live rows and 0 dead rows; 7 rows in sample, 7 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_amop"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_amop": found 0 removable, 945 nonremovable row versions in 7 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_amop"
INFO:  "pg_amop": scanned 7 of 7 pages, containing 945 live rows and 0 dead rows; 945 rows in sample, 945 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_amproc"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_amproc": found 0 removable, 697 nonremovable row versions in 5 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_amproc"
INFO:  "pg_amproc": scanned 5 of 5 pages, containing 697 live rows and 0 dead rows; 697 rows in sample, 697 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_language"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_language": found 0 removable, 4 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_language"
INFO:  "pg_language": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 4 live rows and 0 dead rows; 4 rows in sample, 4 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_largeobject_metadata"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_largeobject_metadata": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_largeobject_metadata"
INFO:  "pg_largeobject_metadata": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_aggregate"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_aggregate": found 0 removable, 157 nonremovable row versions in 2 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_aggregate"
INFO:  "pg_aggregate": scanned 2 of 2 pages, containing 157 live rows and 0 dead rows; 157 rows in sample, 157 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_statistic_ext"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_statistic_ext": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_statistic_ext"
INFO:  "pg_statistic_ext": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_opfamily"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_opfamily": found 0 removable, 146 nonremovable row versions in 2 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_opfamily"
INFO:  "pg_opfamily": scanned 2 of 2 pages, containing 146 live rows and 0 dead rows; 146 rows in sample, 146 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "information_schema.sql_features"
INFO:  "information_schema.sql_features": found 0 removable, 756 nonremovable row versions in 8 pages
INFO:  analyzing "information_schema.sql_features"
INFO:  "sql_features": scanned 8 of 8 pages, containing 756 live rows and 0 dead rows; 756 rows in sample, 756 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_trigger"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_trigger": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_trigger"
INFO:  "pg_trigger": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_event_trigger"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_event_trigger": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_event_trigger"
INFO:  "pg_event_trigger": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_description"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_description": found 0 removable, 5170 nonremovable row versions in 45 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_description"
INFO:  "pg_description": scanned 45 of 45 pages, containing 5170 live rows and 0 dead rows; 5170 rows in sample, 5170 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_cast"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_cast": found 0 removable, 229 nonremovable row versions in 2 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_cast"
INFO:  "pg_cast": scanned 2 of 2 pages, containing 229 live rows and 0 dead rows; 229 rows in sample, 229 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_enum"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_enum": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_enum"
INFO:  "pg_enum": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_namespace"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_namespace": found 0 removable, 4 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_namespace"
INFO:  "pg_namespace": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 4 live rows and 0 dead rows; 4 rows in sample, 4 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_conversion"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_conversion": found 0 removable, 128 nonremovable row versions in 2 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_conversion"
INFO:  "pg_conversion": scanned 2 of 2 pages, containing 128 live rows and 0 dead rows; 128 rows in sample, 128 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_depend"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_depend": found 86 removable, 1763 nonremovable row versions in 14 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_depend"
INFO:  "pg_depend": scanned 13 of 13 pages, containing 1761 live rows and 2 dead rows; 1761 rows in sample, 1761 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_database"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_database": found 0 removable, 21 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_database"
INFO:  "pg_database": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 21 live rows and 0 dead rows; 21 rows in sample, 21 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_tablespace"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_tablespace": found 0 removable, 2 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_tablespace"
INFO:  "pg_tablespace": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 2 live rows and 0 dead rows; 2 rows in sample, 2 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_auth_members"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_auth_members": found 0 removable, 3 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_auth_members"
INFO:  "pg_auth_members": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 3 live rows and 0 dead rows; 3 rows in sample, 3 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_shdepend"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_shdepend": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_shdepend"
INFO:  "pg_shdepend": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_shdescription"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_shdescription": found 0 removable, 3 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_shdescription"
INFO:  "pg_shdescription": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 3 live rows and 0 dead rows; 3 rows in sample, 3 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_ts_config"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_ts_config": found 0 removable, 29 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_ts_config"
INFO:  "pg_ts_config": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 29 live rows and 0 dead rows; 29 rows in sample, 29 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_ts_config_map"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_ts_config_map": found 0 removable, 551 nonremovable row versions in 3 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_ts_config_map"
INFO:  "pg_ts_config_map": scanned 3 of 3 pages, containing 551 live rows and 0 dead rows; 551 rows in sample, 551 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_ts_dict"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_ts_dict": found 0 removable, 29 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_ts_dict"
INFO:  "pg_ts_dict": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 29 live rows and 0 dead rows; 29 rows in sample, 29 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_ts_parser"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_ts_parser": found 0 removable, 1 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_ts_parser"
INFO:  "pg_ts_parser": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 1 live rows and 0 dead rows; 1 rows in sample, 1 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_ts_template"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_ts_template": found 0 removable, 5 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_ts_template"
INFO:  "pg_ts_template": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 5 live rows and 0 dead rows; 5 rows in sample, 5 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_extension"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_extension": found 0 removable, 1 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_extension"
INFO:  "pg_extension": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 1 live rows and 0 dead rows; 1 rows in sample, 1 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_foreign_data_wrapper"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_foreign_data_wrapper": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_foreign_data_wrapper"
INFO:  "pg_foreign_data_wrapper": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_foreign_server"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_foreign_server": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_foreign_server"
INFO:  "pg_foreign_server": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_policy"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_policy": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_policy"
INFO:  "pg_policy": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_replication_origin"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_replication_origin": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_replication_origin"
INFO:  "pg_replication_origin": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_default_acl"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_default_acl": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_default_acl"
INFO:  "pg_default_acl": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_init_privs"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_init_privs": found 0 removable, 220 nonremovable row versions in 3 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_init_privs"
INFO:  "pg_init_privs": scanned 3 of 3 pages, containing 220 live rows and 0 dead rows; 220 rows in sample, 220 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_seclabel"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_seclabel": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_seclabel"
INFO:  "pg_seclabel": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_shseclabel"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_shseclabel": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_shseclabel"
INFO:  "pg_shseclabel": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_collation"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_collation": found 0 removable, 2245 nonremovable row versions in 41 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_collation"
INFO:  "pg_collation": scanned 41 of 41 pages, containing 2245 live rows and 0 dead rows; 2245 rows in sample, 2245 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_parameter_acl"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_parameter_acl": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_parameter_acl"
INFO:  "pg_parameter_acl": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_partitioned_table"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_partitioned_table": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_partitioned_table"
INFO:  "pg_partitioned_table": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_range"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_range": found 0 removable, 6 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_range"
INFO:  "pg_range": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 6 live rows and 0 dead rows; 6 rows in sample, 6 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_transform"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_transform": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_transform"
INFO:  "pg_transform": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_attrdef"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_attrdef": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_attrdef"
INFO:  "pg_attrdef": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_constraint"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_constraint": found 0 removable, 112 nonremovable row versions in 3 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_constraint"
INFO:  "pg_constraint": scanned 3 of 3 pages, containing 112 live rows and 0 dead rows; 112 rows in sample, 112 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_inherits"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_inherits": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_inherits"
INFO:  "pg_inherits": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_index"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_index": found 1 removable, 173 nonremovable row versions in 4 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_index"
INFO:  "pg_index": scanned 4 of 4 pages, containing 173 live rows and 0 dead rows; 173 rows in sample, 173 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_operator"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_operator": found 0 removable, 799 nonremovable row versions in 14 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_operator"
INFO:  "pg_operator": scanned 14 of 14 pages, containing 799 live rows and 0 dead rows; 799 rows in sample, 799 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_sequence"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_sequence": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_sequence"
INFO:  "pg_sequence": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_user_mapping"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_user_mapping": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_user_mapping"
INFO:  "pg_user_mapping": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_subscription"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_subscription": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_subscription"
INFO:  "pg_subscription": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_attribute"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_attribute": found 230 removable, 3345 nonremovable row versions in 77 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_attribute"
INFO:  "pg_attribute": scanned 61 of 61 pages, containing 3313 live rows and 32 dead rows; 3313 rows in sample, 3313 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_proc"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_proc": found 0 removable, 3297 nonremovable row versions in 96 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_proc"
INFO:  "pg_proc": scanned 96 of 96 pages, containing 3297 live rows and 0 dead rows; 3297 rows in sample, 3297 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_publication_namespace"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_publication_namespace": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_publication_namespace"
INFO:  "pg_publication_namespace": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_publication_rel"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_publication_rel": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_publication_rel"
INFO:  "pg_publication_rel": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_subscription_rel"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_subscription_rel": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_subscription_rel"
INFO:  "pg_subscription_rel": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "information_schema.sql_implementation_info"
INFO:  "information_schema.sql_implementation_info": found 0 removable, 12 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "information_schema.sql_implementation_info"
INFO:  "sql_implementation_info": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 12 live rows and 0 dead rows; 12 rows in sample, 12 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "information_schema.sql_parts"
INFO:  "information_schema.sql_parts": found 0 removable, 11 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "information_schema.sql_parts"
INFO:  "sql_parts": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 11 live rows and 0 dead rows; 11 rows in sample, 11 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "information_schema.sql_sizing"
INFO:  "information_schema.sql_sizing": found 0 removable, 23 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "information_schema.sql_sizing"
INFO:  "sql_sizing": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 23 live rows and 0 dead rows; 23 rows in sample, 23 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_largeobject"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_largeobject": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_largeobject"
INFO:  "pg_largeobject": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "public.customers"
INFO:  "public.customers": found 0 removable, 91 nonremovable row versions in 2 pages
INFO:  analyzing "public.customers"
INFO:  "customers": scanned 2 of 2 pages, containing 91 live rows and 0 dead rows; 91 rows in sample, 91 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "public.categories"
INFO:  "public.categories": found 0 removable, 8 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "public.categories"
INFO:  "categories": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 8 live rows and 0 dead rows; 8 rows in sample, 8 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "public.employees"
INFO:  "public.employees": found 0 removable, 9 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "public.employees"
INFO:  "employees": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 9 live rows and 0 dead rows; 9 rows in sample, 9 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "public.order_details"
INFO:  "public.order_details": found 0 removable, 2155 nonremovable row versions in 15 pages
INFO:  analyzing "public.order_details"
INFO:  "order_details": scanned 15 of 15 pages, containing 2155 live rows and 0 dead rows; 2155 rows in sample, 2155 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "public.orders"
INFO:  "public.orders": found 0 removable, 830 nonremovable row versions in 7 pages
INFO:  analyzing "public.orders"
INFO:  "orders": scanned 7 of 7 pages, containing 830 live rows and 0 dead rows; 830 rows in sample, 830 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "public.products"
INFO:  "public.products": found 0 removable, 77 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "public.products"
INFO:  "products": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 77 live rows and 0 dead rows; 77 rows in sample, 77 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "public.shippers"
INFO:  "public.shippers": found 0 removable, 3 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "public.shippers"
INFO:  "shippers": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 3 live rows and 0 dead rows; 3 rows in sample, 3 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "public.monthly_date_dimension"
INFO:  "public.monthly_date_dimension": found 0 removable, 23 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "public.monthly_date_dimension"
INFO:  "monthly_date_dimension": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 23 live rows and 0 dead rows; 23 rows in sample, 23 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "public.countries_only"
INFO:  "public.countries_only": found 0 removable, 69 nonremovable row versions in 1 pages
INFO:  analyzing "public.countries_only"
INFO:  "countries_only": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 69 live rows and 0 dead rows; 69 rows in sample, 69 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_rewrite"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_rewrite": found 0 removable, 143 nonremovable row versions in 13 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_rewrite"
INFO:  "pg_rewrite": scanned 13 of 13 pages, containing 143 live rows and 0 dead rows; 143 rows in sample, 143 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_db_role_setting"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_db_role_setting": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_db_role_setting"
INFO:  "pg_db_role_setting": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_class"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_class": found 23 removable, 442 nonremovable row versions in 13 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_class"
INFO:  "pg_class": scanned 12 of 12 pages, containing 441 live rows and 2 dead rows; 441 rows in sample, 441 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_publication"
INFO:  "pg_catalog.pg_publication": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages
INFO:  analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_publication"
INFO:  "pg_publication": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
INFO:  vacuuming "public.date_and_country"
INFO:  "public.date_and_country": found 0 removable, 1587 nonremovable row versions in 14 pages
INFO:  analyzing "public.date_and_country"
INFO:  "date_and_country": scanned 14 of 14 pages, containing 1587 live rows and 0 dead rows; 1587 rows in sample, 1587 estimated total rows
VACUUM

Query returned successfully in 22 secs 115 msec.
```

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I'm sorry but am I supposed to "join" every single subsection of Stack Exchange now? First I tried posting on Stack Overflow, was advised to go post on Super User. Now you're telling me I should go to the DBA Stack Exchange subsection instead. This back and forth is quite frustrating.

Comment: “I'm sorry but am I supposed to "join" every single subsection of Stack Exchange now?” Yes. It is not difficult to create accounts on Stack Exchange sites; it is often just the case if clicking an approval prompt and that’s it. And the only reason you are asked to join is because you posted and off topic question to Stack Overflow. The post should have not been cross posted at all let alone to Super User. This might seem complex but it is very easy to clean up. Just delete this post and join the Database Administrators SE and deal with the question there.

Comment: @Giacomo1968, this question is about *pagefile.sys*, as much as it is about a database query, and is appropriate on SupperUser, IMHO.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I would much prefer for the question to remain here since it got the answer I was looking for! Or can it be migrated entirely, answer included? No idea.

Comment: @MV I would recommend you delete the question on the [Database Administrators SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/334564/20395) site, let this one be and accept the answer here.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Done! Deleted from Database Administrators SE. And sorry if I came across as a bit aggressive there earlier. It's been a frustrating 24 hours. :))

Comment: @MV Understood. It all worked out in the end.

Comment: In a comment you said you had 4gb of physical RAM,  I suggest you upgrade to at least 8gb so windows is less reliant on the pagefile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's normal for the size of *pagefile.sys* to change if you have let it be set automatically. Its use indicates the PC did *not* have sufficient RAM to run the SQL query in memory, so it started to swap out sections to disk -- an exceedingly slow operation, even with SSD. Next time the PC is rebooted, *pagefile.sys* should shrink to its initial setting.

However, you may decide to [set the size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/how-to-determine-the-appropriate-page-file-size-for-64-bit-versions-of-windows) of that file yourself to optimize large queries and to reduce continual resizing of the file, which can cause fragmentation.

The size of *pagefile.sys* is set by the System Properties Control Panel.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, type `sysdm.cpl`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, and allow the *System Properties* CPL to run as Administrator.
- On the *Advanced* tab, select *Performance | Settings*.
- On the *Advanced* tab of the *Performance Options* dialog, select *Virtual memory | Change*.
- Use the *Virtual Memory* dialog to set the size of *pagefile.sys*.

You can find various recommendations for setting that size. My inclination is to set a *Custom size* with initial size and maximum size set to the same value to prevent constant growth and shrinking on a HDD. The value suggested ranges from *half* the physical RAM (e.g., in the image below, from a 4 GB RAM machine, it's set to 2 GB), to *twice* that of RAM. Experiment with different amounts to see what is optimal for running SQL queries on *your* PC -- rebooting after changing page file size.

[image: Setting virtual memory]

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful response! Follow-up question: checking the currently allocated value for my computer's virtual memory, it is already set to 9203 MB, with my machine having 4 GB of physical RAM. So it seems to (sort of) be aligned with your recommended values. Yet I suspect that it was smaller before my problem with the query, without reverting to its initial values after rebooting. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, if you let the system resize it, it may trend towards the maximum. And setting it *lower* (e.g., **2 GB**) might actually speed the query, since that reduces swapping to disk (though it might not, too -- try it and see). BTW, perform a *full* reboot; if Windows *Fast Startup* is on, it caches memory and does not truly reboot: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

Comment: Will do! One more thing before I test out your ideas: in the VIrtual Memory window it also says that the "Space Available" for my C drive is close to 17 GB, but when I check by the usual Windows Explorer route, it only shows 7 GB as available space. Is that ... normal? Is that almost 10 GB difference related to pagefile.sys (which coincidentally is around 9 GB itself) ?

Comment: oops... that is *not* enough headroom for Windows. Clear out some room! In addition to *pagefile.sys*, there's *swapfile.sys* and possibly *hiberfil.sys*.

Comment: Update: SUCCESS! The full reboot did the job! And pagefile.sys also went back to a smaller value (2175 MB vs the 9203 MB that it was at earlier). Thank you so much for the help! It was seriously driving me crazy.

Comment: @MV, glad it worked! Please mark the answer if it resolved the issue. And clean up space on C:  . Some PC's are being sold with very small SSD's, which is insufficient for Windows. Linux, which uses less drive space, and Chrome, which stores much in the cloud can get by, but not Windows. See about cleaning WinSxs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-11), temp files, etc.

Comment: @MV Mazel tov! Happy this solved the issue! I would recommend you upvote this answer and check it off as the answer as well. You see? It all worked out in the end.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Now that you mention it, I did indeed notice that WinSxs was getting a bit too large as well. Yet another super helpful link! Thank you once more!